# IEEE802.3af/at PoE/PoE+ ethernet repeater to non-PoE laptop port for network access

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet

This is my first post and I would LOVE some help.

I'm in a situation where the customer owns our intranet/"VendorNet", which is a VLAN that represents all the servers and devices to which I need to communicate (e.g. remote desktop into a server).

For various reasons, I am not allowed to use wireless APs to gain wireless access to ports activated on this VLAN and must be hard-wired directly from my computer into the port. My issue is that I am not able to reach where I need to go with the 100m cat5e restriction. The customer has permitted me to use a wired, 1-port ethernet repeater to extend my range.

So here are my questions:

Is it possible to plug an ethernet cable directly from my laptop's standard ethernet port into an ethernet repeater, then the ethernet repeater into a port capable of communicating over the network I'd like to access, and be able to remote desktop into a server on said network? What if this repeater is PoE/PoE+? Even if the repeater is IEEE802.3af/at (af class 1-4), will it still fry my port/network adapter?

For some reason or another, they will only let me use a 1-port ethernet repeater and not a dumb switch or anything like that. This has really tied my hands and made efficient work a genuine challenge. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

short answer yes you could with no problem , repeater should work ***as a two port switch*** . i believe in that if this two port repeater is POE or POE+ just main that it will need extra power adapter to provide the host with this POE but not affect its data payload . so first of all test this repeater with simple ping .

Comment: Actually, the repeater works as a two-port hub rather than a two-port switch. It is a layer-1, not a layer-2 device.

Comment: @RonMaupin Most of these so-called repeaters I looked at support full-duplex operation. So despite the name, they really are layer-2 devices.

Comment: @richardb, yes, they can use full-duplex (they only have two ports), but they do nothing at layer-2. A layer-2 device will at least inspect a frame, and it uses a layer-2 address, but the repeaters don't.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the repeater will be a PoE device, except that it may power itself with PoE.

In any case, your laptop should have no problem because you can plug it into a PoE switch port and not fry it. PoE will not be sent unless the end-device requests it. This was a primary concern when the PoE standards were originally created.